# Jackson generate JsonSchema from string JSON object

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jsonschema

I have a following object:

```
String jsonObject = "{\"cat\": \"nice cat\"}"
```

From this I want to get `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema` class object.

But I can't find a way how to achieve this without having a Java class beforehand.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The goal I am trying to achieve is to generate Kafka Connect Schema from a JSON string. For this I need first to get `JsonSchema` from a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and more thought put into it, such method does not exist for obvious reasons. Imagine for example a valid JSON:

```
{
    "a": [],
    "b": null
}
```

Then there is no way to tell what are types of `a` or `b`.

Therefore I need to be more clever here in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I wouldn't say it shouldn't exist though.  F# has the idea of type providers where you can provide example data and it can generate the type from that.   
 http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html  I see the original question as similar to that - if I can provide sample data, I should be able to generate a json schema from that.  I would think nulls and empty arrays would throw an error.